# Criteria across all range excel

Tags: excel

I am using average across a range but only want to take cells that:

1. Are a number (isnumber())
2. Who's key match a particular string (form response = dataA)

   I am using

   ```
   =AVERAGEIF('Form Responses 1'!$L$2:$L$143, AND(ISNUMBER('Form Responses 1'!L2), 'Form Responses 1'!C3=Data!A3))
   ```

My issue comes from anything within the and() statement. How do I make sure that it compares and checks the appropriate cells?

Cheers

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "key"? Do you mean column name in your range or is the key within the cells you are trying to average?

Comment: Yeah so example column A is the team name and I want to do various averages depending on their team. So I'm just comparing the team name (example "Team 1" and make sure they match)

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to do an array formula.  In your cell with your formula, instead of simply pressing ENTER, try Pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to see if that does what you want.

Comment: For more info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Comment: It didn't really work

Comment: @alexp2603, I deleted my first answer since it wasn't working well. Can you post a sample of your data and a desired output? I think that would help quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Form Responses 1'!$L$2:$L$143, 'Form Responses 1'!$C$2:$C$143, Data!A3)
```

It averages in range `$L$2:$L$143` the numeric cells where column C matches the key in Cell `A3` of worksheet `Data`.